# How to join data from two lists in a datagrid through binding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I have two lists and want to join them through binding on a DataGrid. Consider the lists to have a lot of data, so manipulating the list in the code behind is not an option:

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class Category : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    ...
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    private ObservableCollection<Person> PersonList;
    private ObservableCollection<Category> CategoryList;

    ...

    this.PersonDataList.ItemsSource = this.PersonList;

    ...

}
```

The XAML will be something like:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="PersonDataList" EnableColumnVirtualization="True" EnableRowVirtualization="True" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
   <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding FirstName,Mode=OneWay}" />
   <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding LastName,Mode=OneWay}" />
   <DataGridTextColumn Header="Category ID" Binding="{Binding CategoryId,Mode=OneWay}" Visibility="Hidden" />
   <DataGridTextColumn Header="Category" Binding="{Binding CategoryName,Mode=OneWay}" />
</DataGrid>
```

I can make it by a ValueConverter, but then a change of a CategoryName in the CategoryList will not show up in the DataGrid, and that is very bad.

I can also make it by using a DataGridComboBoxColumn, but I do not want to populate the CategoryList on each row of Persons in the DataGrid, and I do not want to show a dropdown box - just plain text.

Is there a way to solve this by using a DataGridTemplateColumn and HierarchicalDataTemplate?